# Optimizing Cypher Query to handle quote chars

Tags: c#, neo4j, cypher

I'm using the following Query to create a node in neo4j v4 with a Name, but I'm having trouble if the name contains a '

How should I rewrite that Query so that we can use Names which contains a ' ?

```
 string name = "ÖöÜüÄäßµ@€-&'.";
 var query2Neo = "CREATE (p:Person { samAccountName: $name })";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to avoid these kinds of quotation-clash issues is to use a [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/) to pass the string value to the Cypher code instead of attempting to hard-code the string in the code. This approach is preferable anyway, as it leads to code that is more readable and potentially more efficient, and avoids Cypher-injection attacks.

For example, if the string is passed as a `name` parameter, your code would be simply:

```
var query2Neo = ("CREATE (p:Person { samAccountName: $name })");
```